# Storing a function that may have parameter or not, to variable. Action<T> with unknown numbers and types of variables

Tags: c#, delegates, console-application

I'm working on a command parser class for console application but I got stucked at the storing command function to variable. I want to store a function that may have parameter or not, to commandFunc variable in Command object.

These codes work with functions without parameters. How can I get parameter support to this? For example: a function like output(string msg){ .. }

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CommandParser.AddCommand(new Command() { commandText = "time", commandFunc = new Action(time) });

        CommandParser.Loop();
    }

    private static void time()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
}
```

In CommandParser.Loop, it searches for inputted command in List< Command > and then runs Execute method from it.

```
public class Command
{
    public string commandText { get; set; }
    public Action commandFunc { get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        this.commandFunc();
    }
}
```

For example the execute method can be someting like this:

```
public void Execute(Parameters params)
{
    this.commandFunc(params);
}
```

PS: CommandParser.Loop()

```
    public static void Loop()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.Write(prefix);
            string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            Command cmdInput = commands.Find(x => x.commandText.Contains(input[0]));
            if(cmdInput != new Command())
            {
                cmdInput.Execute();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prefix + "Command not found!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would you expect it to convert from a string array to the right parameter types?

Comment: I wrote it to tell my question better. It's just a example.

Comment: But it goes to the heart of an unexplained part of the question: if you're going to have different commands with different expected numbers of parameters, how do you expect to execute them? Where would the data come from?

Comment: In CommandParser.Loop() it gets input with Console.ReadLine() and splits it by empty space. The first element of the returned array is commandText and the other elements are parameters. Added the Loop function to question. Check it out.

Comment: Well your loop doesn't show it passing anything to the command... (It's not clear what you expect `cmdInput != new Command()` to achieve as a condition, either... I suspect you want `cmdInput != null`.) Maybe you could just use an `Action<string[]>` and let the commands parse their input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you basically need to do is extend the object hierarchy.

In C#, generics don't allow `Something<void>`, so what you need to do is:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}
```

This is your current implementation with the interface added

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    public string commandText { get; set; }
    public Action commandFunc { get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        this.commandFunc();
    }
}
```

And is a generic implementation for delegate with arguments

```
public class Command<T> : ICommand
{
    public string       commandText  { get; set; }
    public Action<T>    commandFunc  { get; set; }
    public T            commandParam { get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        this.commandFunc(commandParam);
    }
}
```

If you need implementation for more parameters, you could either copy the original one or use `Tuple` class as the generic parameter (e.g. `Tuple<string, int>`).

**As mentioned by Jon Skeet in comments:**
Another thing is that you'll probably need to parse the parameter(s) (represented by `commandParam`) inside these generic commands. You should initialize these commands with a parameter (e.g. delegate) to parse the parameter(s). Doing this outside of the commands would be a mess and break the whole genericity/interface idea. But it might work on a smaller scale.